# Module.exports mixes two different Joi validations with Hapi.js

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

Not sure if the title explains what the problem is accurately so hope this gives you better light as to what I'm experiencing.

I have a route that uses pretty much the exact same code as another route that is only accessible to admins to make updates. So route "A": route/update_fees has a set of Joi validations that I want to use under route "B": route/update_agent_fees. So I created a validations folder and exported the validations from route "A" this is the file below:

```
"use strict";

const Joi = require("joi");

module.exports = {
    payload: {
        fees: Joi.object().keys({
            default: Joi.array().items(
                Joi.object({
                    period: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Days to consider the fee"),
                    fee: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Fee's to be charged")
                })
            ).description("Array of fees to be charge in any shipment status").min(1),
            fees_status: Joi.object().keys({
                101: Joi.array().items(
                        Joi.object({
                            period: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Days to consider the fee"),
                            fee: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Fee's to be charged")
                        })
                    ).description("Array of fees for 101 shipment status").min(1),
                102: Joi.array().items(
                    Joi.object({
                        period: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Days to consider the fee"),
                        fee: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Fee's to be charged")
                    })
                ).description("Array of fees for 102 shipment status").min(1),
            }).description("Fees customizable for 101 and 102 status").min(1)
        }).xor("default", "fees_status")
    },
    headers: Joi.object({
        "csrf-decorator": Joi.string().required(),
        "accept-language": Joi.string().required(),
        "user-agent": Joi.string().required()
    }).options({
        allowUnknown: true
    })
}
```

In the second file, I have required route A and added and modified the only change I need for route B to work:

```
"use strict";

const Joi = require("joi");
const set_agent_fee_rates_validation = require("./set_agent_fee_rates");

let admin_set_agent_fee_rates_validation = set_agent_fee_rates_validation;
admin_set_agent_fee_rates_validation.payload.agent_id = Joi.string().required();

module.exports = admin_set_agent_fee_rates_validation;
```

The problem is that when I go to my swagger, I can see that `agent_id` is required in both api endpoints when it should only be required in route B.

Any help with understanding the problem here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than exporting an object, then modifying it for B, why not export a function? That function can return a validation object, one for A, then one for B?

Another option would be to deep clone the validation object before modifying it.

Here is how you would use a function, instead of a raw object literal

```
const Joi = require("joi");

const make_validator = (optional) => {
  const payload = {
    fees: Joi.object().keys({
      default: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object({
          period: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Days to consider the fee"),
          fee: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Fee's to be charged")
        })
      ).description("Array of fees to be charge in any shipment status").min(1),
      fees_status: Joi.object().keys({
        101: Joi.array().items(
          Joi.object({
            period: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Days to consider the fee"),
            fee: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Fee's to be charged")
          })
        ).description("Array of fees for 101 shipment status").min(1),
        102: Joi.array().items(
          Joi.object({
            period: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Days to consider the fee"),
            fee: Joi.number().integer().required().description("Fee's to be charged")
          })
        ).description("Array of fees for 102 shipment status").min(1),
      }).description("Fees customizable for 101 and 102 status").min(1)
    }).xor("default", "fees_status")
  };

  if (optional && optional.payload) {
    const new_payload = Object.assign({}, payload, optional.payload);
  } else {
    const new_payload = payload;
  }

  return {
    new_payload,
    headers: Joi.object({
      "csrf-decorator": Joi.string().required(),
      "accept-language": Joi.string().required(),
      "user-agent": Joi.string().required()
    }).options({
      allowUnknown: true
    })}
  }

module.exports = make_validator
```

Then the second snippet becomes

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const make_validator = require("./set_agent_fee_rates");

const set_agent_fee_rates_validation = make_validator();

const admin_set_agent_fee_rates_validation = make_validator({
  payload: {
    agent_id: Joi.string().required()
  }
});

module.exports = admin_set_agent_fee_rates_validation;
```

Comment: I see where you're going and was about to give you a best answer. I have done that on my code now after reading how module.exports get cached. I feel like the chosen answer should have the code that shows how things are achieved. But if no one else answers the question, I will come back and chose you as the best answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ok, will add once I'm in front of a laptop.

Comment: Thank you kindly!